FastAPI running over uvicorn, cant be connected to cross machine/network
Before i describe the problem in more detail; I have tried a ton of stuff, and been working on this issue for many hours. All other help articles, old forum answers and Gemini & Chatgpt answers have been useless.
Situation:
I have machine A (The server, running my API using fastapi. The app starts without a problem.) Below a screenshot from the console output.
(Detail: The app is launched via ssh. the screenshot was NOT taken on machine A, as machine A is running Ubuntu server, so I have to ssh into it to take screenshots from the console. I have however also tried to run it without ssh, just on machine A by connecting a screen and keyboard.)

The urllib3 warning, is due to a bit of a version conflict with torch, doesn't effect anything as far as I know though. Just in case it does, I have also tried running everything in a venv, which eliminates the warning, but the problem persists.
From Machine B, (The frontend, running on my laptop, right now since there is no frontend, we are using Postman to test functionality) I send a package, for user signUp to the Backend.


Problem
In Postman, this shows:

There is nothing in the console on machine A (The backend) when i send the request, and the error in postman appears after a fraction of a second.
The firewall on machine A is completely disabled and appropriate settings have been made in the iptables
What have I tried?
I have;

Changed the port

Enabled firewall

Used CORS MIddleware

Used without middleware

opened the port on the router for TCP

set the --host for uvicorn to 0.0.0.0 and to the private IP of machine A

set the url in postman to 0.0.0.0 or to the private IP of machine A

tried to connect cross network after opening the port on the router, using the public ip and port 8000

used the ping command from machine B (frontend) to check whether the backend is reachable, and it was: 

used a CORS middleware config that allows ["*"] origins (I read that using * origins only works when disallowing credentials, so i tried all combinations of settings that might work regarding this limitation)

Checked wether the backend is listening on port 8000 (with all combinations of IPs): 

Changed DNS address from the standard to 9.9.9.9


Nothing seems to change anything... There has been absolutely zero change in the result, no matter what i changed
I have concluded that this is a issue of routing to the host (backend) and not an issue of the python script/fastAPI or uvicorn, as it does work when i try to send a packet from the same machine (machine A, localhost) but not cross machine or cross network. Another reason for my conclusion is the fact that there is no difference in the error in postman, when the uvicorn app is running vs when it isn't.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

127.0.0.1 is your localhost (i.e. the same computer - it'll always point to the computer you're running the command/application on - so in this case, the client you're running postman on), so you can at skip testing that unless you're running the API locally on your own computer. CORS is not relevant for testing in Postman. First: start by running uvicorn with 0.0.0.0 as the bind address to bind to all interfaces, verify that it's listening to that (just as postgres does in your netstat output). Then verify what the status of the firewall is, and ensure the port is open from your client.

When binding to 0.0.0.0, you'll still have to use the IP of your server when connecting from postman. 0.0.0.0 just means "every interface connected to this machine" - and is only relevant on that local machine, it's not a routable address/something to connect to over the network.

@MatsLindh
I have set the --host flag to 0.0.0.0 now and verified using netstat that it is indeed listening. Now I am sending a request over psotman, to the private IP of the backend machine. sadly, the error persists, but is now saying this:
Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 192.168.2.84:8000
No output in the backend's console

How did you verify that the firewall is open for that port? Include that information in your question as well; you can also verify that it isn't a postman issue by using curl to make a request or pasting the URL into your browser (with the .2.84 address). Are these machines physically different machines? Or are they VMs with NAT enabled? Are they on the same subnet?

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.84 port 80 after 5 ms: No route to host
and
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.84 port 8000 after 6 ms: No route to host



sudo ufw status gives Status: inactive

Are you sure your computer is allowing traffic out on port 8000? What happens if you curl the API on the server itself, using the internal ip? And are these physically on the same network, or are you using VMs?

no im not using VMs and ufw is also inactive on my machine (front end) so on both machines. if i curl the api on the server itself this happens: lucira@lucira:~$ curl 0.0.0.0:8000
{"detail":"Not Found"} and in the console of the server running it displays this: INFO:     127.0.0.1:40770 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found so here it seems everything is working. just cross machines doesnt work

You might want to look at what iptables are showing on both machines as well (ufw isn't the only level of possible network handling), and wireshark/tcpdump can tell you exactly what is being transmitted and responded to between the servers from your local machine. I assume that ssh ...2.84 works from your client as that's what you've shown in your first example.

yes ssh works on port 22 and iptables looks like this for the frontend: https://i.imgur.com/BHAHxE6.png
and this for the backend: https://pastebin.com/8vvD9Sx6

Please write the images as text, so people using screen readers or people who want to copy your text can do so.

You might find this answer helpful.

you just have to run uvicorn with these flags
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT

